# What does queryCommandValue("FontSize") return?

Tags: c#, ihtmldocument2

I am trying to get the font size of selected range in a html document.
I used queryCommandValue to get it. 
Some times it return an integer. And some times it is not. I don't know what is it.

And I also tried another way to get the fontsize by getting the parent emlement's style.
But it's not always correct for there could be different font size in its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method returns a value between 1 and 7, for font sizes from "small" to "large", like in GMail.

If you want to get a font size in points or pixels, use

```
mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange range = _dom.selection.createRange() as mshtml.IHTMLTxtRange;
if (range != null)
{
   mshtml.IHTMLElement2 elem = range.parentElement() as mshtml.IHTMLElement2;
   fontSize.Text = elem.currentStyle.fontSize.ToString()
}
```

Comment: Setting the selection being key to getting a predictable font size.

Comment: I have tried this way. But it is not correct. I set each <p> with font size 16pt and body font size 10pt. Then I selected multiple lines. It just got the body's font size 10pt.